# P unless Q, in which case R

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I changed the variables in the title to make it easier in a google search in case anyone else needed to look up this problem.

In Leblanc and Wisdom's *Deductive Logic, Third Edition,* there is the following truth-table on page 230:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what the formula for $A_1$ unless $A_2$, in which case $A_3$ would be. For instance,

(i) $(A_2 \vee A_1) \supset A_3$

does not fit the entry for the truth value assignment: $A_1$ as **F**, $A_2$ as **F** and $A_3$ as **F**

(ii) $ \neg(A_2 \supset A_3) \supset A_1$
does not fit the entry for the truth value assignment: $A_1$ as **T**, $A_2$ as **T** and $A_3$ as **F**

(iii) $A_1 \supset \neg(A_2 \supset A_3)$ does not fit the entry for any truth value assignment: $A_2$ as **T** and $A_3$ as **F**

(iv) $A_3 \supset (A_1 \vee A_2)$ does not fit the entry for the truth value assignment: $A_1$ as **F**, $A_2$ as **F** and $A_3$ as **F**

> *Does anyone know how to translate this statement or could it be that the book had a misprint in the last column of the truth-table??*
>   Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How about $(A_2 \supset A_3) \wedge (\lnot A_2 \supset A_1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: 'unless' can be replaced with 'if not'.

So: '$A_1$ unless $A_2$, in which case $A_3$' becomes: '$A_1$ if not $A_2$, but if $A_2$ then $A_3$'.

'But' is of course 'and', and so we get:

$(\neg A_2 \rightarrow A_1)\land (A_2 \rightarrow A_3)$

Using your notation:

$(\neg A_2 \supset A_1) \land (A_2 \supset A_3)$

Notice that if we commute:

$(A_2 \supset A_3)\land (\neg A_2 \supset A_1)$

we get what the book identified as the equivalent '$A_3$ if $A_2$, otherwise $A_1$'

Answer (score 2):

The formulae is rather simple guided by the comment $A_3$ if $A_2$, otherwise $A_1$. $$(A_3 \wedge A_2) \vee (A_1 \wedge \neg A_2) $$

Comment: Could you please provide your reasoning used to get to the answer? Your answer could potentially be the best if you do so. Especially things like how does 'otherwise' get translated?? Thanks

Comment: Usually $A_3$ if $A_2$ would mean $A_2 \supset A_3$ or $\neg A_2 \vee A_3$ but I don't see how you got there and how do you interpret otherwise? Or do you mean you just directly know that that is the translation without any steps in between??

Comment: This is the guideline of my thoughts. If we define the function $f(A_1, A_2, A_3)$ it will be like this: $if (A_2) return A_3; else return A_1$. If $A_2$ is false the first clause of my formula will be false and the value of $A_3$ will be ignored. The same happens in the other case. More over, when $A_2$ is true, the second clause will be ignored and the value of the formula will be $A_3$, which is exactly what we want, same happens with $A_1$